# Keeping content in sync when building a new site

Tags: nodes, upgrading

I'm moving my company Intranet from D6 to D7, and I'm wondering the best approach to keeping content (nodes) in sync while building and theming the new site. I've cloned the D6 site and did the D7 core and CCK upgrade. But the current Intranet is updated daily with new content that will need to make its way to the new D7 site prior to launch. Is there a way to keep the content in sync during the development stage? Or is there a better way to approach this situation?